# How to use a Arrow Function

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, arrow-functions

I'm just reading up on ES6 features that have been implemented in Node v4.0.0 and saw Arrows. The example from [Arrow Functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) is:

```
var a = [
    "Hydrogen",
    "Helium",
    "Lithium",
    "Beryl­lium"
];
var a2 = a.map(function(s){ return s.length });
var a3 = a.map( s => s.length );
```

My question is how can I include multiple lines of code inside of `a.map( s => s.length );` rather than just returning the length as in this example.

Comment: There are plenty of examples and details in the link you provided, even for multiple lined function, I don't see what can be added here. What exactly are you looking for that you did not find in the doc?

Comment: It's right there in the page you linked to at the very top: `// Basic syntax: (param1, param2, paramN) => { statements } (param1, param2, paramN) => expression // equivalent to:  => { return expression; }`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just wrap your multiple code lines in curly braces like this:

```
var a3 = a.map( s => {
    var temp = s.length;
    return temp;
});
```

Comment: Thats easier than I could ever have dreamed. I am looking forward to it.

Comment: …and don't forget that the `return` is no more implicit then, right.